# Direct login from a link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am using asp.net mvc 5 with owin security, and I have to create a link which will be sent to users email. And when user clicks on the link, they will be login to the system directly.

I still couldn't figure out how to generate that link with username and password..etc.

Can anyone show some light please.

Comment: You should *never* include the username and password in a link. That's a horrible, **horrible** idea. Instead, you can include a token that pseudo logs the user in (they can see basic information) but still requires a password to be manually entered to access anything sensitive. And you'd need to include verbiage in the email stating not to share the link. I don't know how you could easily integrate this with your current security system, but my main point is **don't include usernames and passwords in links**.

Comment: Explain "have to". Your job as a developer is to explain to project owners when something is a *very*, *very* bad idea. A link that automatically logs a user in is a *very*, *very* bad idea. Personally, if the project owner(s) insist on doing it anyways, I'd back out of the project.

Comment: Guys I know what do you mean. But I am not gonna use the username and password directly. I must encrypt or hash or do something so that it is not visible in open eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to generate a link with the username and the password - definitely you shouldn't (+1 for @mason).
If you need to login users from the link you can generate and store a hash/guid/etc in the db for the user and send a link with the userId and the hash via email. -> sth like: mysite.org/login?userid=123&hash=b89eaac7e61417341b710b727768294d0e6a277b

You can create an action to check if the userId and the hash match the data in the db and login the user.
sth like

```
var user = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()).FindByIdAsync(userId)
if(user.Hash == hashFromTheLink)
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(...)
```

Comment: we decided not to do that. but again what you said is the right answer.